# WAMP server is not working

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

I have downloaded some files which have .php extension.

Then I installed *WAMMP* server on my, but I am not able to view those files. I have also turned off the *IIS* from the add/remove windows program. Still, I am not able to view the pages.

Comment: To help, we need a lot more info. What software are you using? Is the server on? How are you trying to connect to it? Are you getting error messages, and if you are, what are they?

Comment: You seem to have a deep misunderstanding about what PHP files are and how “a wamp server” comes into play.

Answer (score 2):

I'm presuming that by WAMP, you are using Apache as your server? You need to find your `www` folder in `C:\WAMP\www` and place files in there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the wamp server I use.

http://www.wampserver.com/en/download.php

I have also used this one in the past.

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Comment: Please do not answer your own question to add information; instead, edit the question.

Comment: what? this is not my question. I was simply giving examples of wamp servers since go one else linked to any.

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt: it is not the same person who asked the question, you should check before voting down. +1 to Samuel.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the wamp server icon on your taskbar, go to Apache and you will find Test Port 80 in there. That will show whether port 80 is available or not. If not, go to httpd.conf file which is in the Apache menu of wamp server, find line Listen 80. Change 80 to 88. Restart All Services in wamp and that should work. Let me know if that helped.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the wamp server icon in the taskbar and test "localhost".
2. If that works, click the "`phpinfo()`" link on the page.
3. If that works too, your wamp server is working and you should be able to execute php files. 
   If not, you need to make sure it is installed properly and started properly.

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to view the pages? Why exactly are you "not able" to do it? Are you aware that PHP files are basically programs that run on a server, and you view their output using a web browser? Assuming that you have actual PHP files (rather than their output) and all the resources that they need, you will have to put them into the source folder that WAMP is configured to display, and then you will be able to view them by going to http://localhost in your web browser.

Answer (score 0):

1. in the run put mmc - on the consol file / add /remove item choose internet information  service and under website turn off the iis
2. if you installed in the past wamp/mysql selete all and reinstall only the wamp